# Java Snake Collision

Tags: java

This is my first time in Stackoverflow and Java programming. I always love classic Snake game, and developing a copy of it is both entertaining and instructive.

My Snake.java has tree attributes;

```
private Position head;
private ArrayList<Position> body;
private char currentDirection;
```

Also, it has move method which takes direction of movement from arrow keys. This method generates a Position “newHead” and places it to where “head” must be after the movement.

```
switch (newDirection) {
case 'u':
    if (currentDirection != 'd') {
        newHead.y = newHead.y - 10;
        currentDirection = 'u';
    } else {
        newHead.y = newHead.y + 10;
    }
    break;
    //This method continues for all directions like that.
```

After this I add “head” to “body”, and use “newHead” as a “head”.

```
body.add(new Position(head.x, head.y));
head = new Position(newHead.x, newHead.y);
body.remove(0);
```

As you can see this delivers smooth movement. However, I cannot figure out how to check collisions to either body or wall while moving. Can you give me some ideas or pseudo code for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the code I wrote for you below to get some ideas. I represent your wall’s position with wallL and wallR.

```
public boolean checkCollision(Position newhead) {
    //To check whether newHead is collided to body, and if it occurs returns true
    for (int i = 0; i < getBodyLength(); i++) {
        if (newhead.x == body.get(i).x && newhead.y == body.get(i).y) {
            return true;
        }
    }
   //To check whether newHead is collided to wall, and if it occurs return true
   if( newhead.x == wallL.x|| newhead.x == wallL.y || newhead.y == wallR.x || newhead.y == wallR.y)
return true;
    return false;
}
```

You need to control collision right before adding your ex head to body.

Comment: I get it, thank you.